# Losing focus after each coded ui test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I've got two testcases:
1. Click on the button. After that Textbox appears. It shows till it has focus.
2. Put some text in Textbox.

Both testcases are in two separate TestMethods. When first test passes, focus goes to visual studio. I guess it happens because of saving results in the studio in some way. It works fine if both actions are in same TestMethod, but I need it to be in different tests. Is there any way to keep focus on application without going to VS?

Here's that methods:

```
[TestMethod]
public void _01_Test_45040_AddProjectButtonClick()
{
    //ai.LeftPanelProjects.AddProjectButton.Click();
    WpfButton btnAddProj = CommonActions.GetControl<WpfButton>(app, "AddButton");
    btnAddProj.ClickField();
}

[TestMethod]
public void _02_Test_45041_TypeProjectName()
{
    WpfEdit txtProjName = CommonActions.GetControl<WpfEdit>(app, "NewProjectTextBox");
    txtProjName.Text = projectName;
}
```

**UPD**: This problem not appearing if using nUnit to run tests. For some reason nUnit does not lose focus. I've migrated all tests to it.

Comment: Maybe you've put some breakpoints?

Comment: No. It happens exactly after test completion even in "Run tests" mode, not "Debug tests". So it is not caused by breakpoints.

Comment: Could you show me your code? It's hard to predict without looking into it
Code and markup

Comment: Added code to the first message.

Comment: I think it's happening because of testmethod attribute. Try to remove it

Comment: It won't be Coded UI Tests without that attribute

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know that they were tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can`t do that. These are two distinct test cases. TestCleanup() and TestInitialize() are being executed between each test, therefore it will always return to VS.

Why don`t you just do that in your second test?

```
[TestMethod]
public void _02_Test_45041_TypeProjectName()
{
    WpfButton btnAddProj = CommonActions.GetControl<WpfButton>(app, "AddButton");
    WpfEdit txtProjName = CommonActions.GetControl<WpfEdit>(app, "NewProjectTextBox");
    btnAddProj.ClickField();        
    txtProjName.Text = projectName;
}
```

Comment: Guess it will be the only way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep them in separate tests then you can call the second method from first.
It goes to VS because the first test method has finished its execution.
You can do this.

```
[TestMethod]
public void _01_Test_45040_AddProjectButtonClick()
{
    //ai.LeftPanelProjects.AddProjectButton.Click();
    WpfButton btnAddProj = CommonActions.GetControl<WpfButton>(app, "AddButton");
    btnAddProj.ClickField();

     //calling the second method
    _02_Test_45041_TypeProjectName();
}

[TestMethod]
public void _02_Test_45041_TypeProjectName()
{
    WpfEdit txtProjName = CommonActions.GetControl<WpfEdit>(app, "NewProjectTextBox");
    txtProjName.Text = projectName;
}
```

Comment: In that case I won't be able to start first test only. Also, I don't think it is good pratcice.